# When would you use Simple subdivision rather than Catmull-Clark subdivision?

Tags: modifiers

Subdivision is selected as Catmull-Clark by default. However, the Blender development team still includes the Simple subdivision in Blender 2.72. Does it serve a purpose? Why should I use the Simple subdivision instead of the Catmull-Clark subdivision?

Here is a picture of the Subsurface panel. You can clearly see the options Catmull-Clark and Simple.

[image: Subsurf panel]

Comment: Simple subsurf just subdivides all faces without moving any geometry.  Catmull-Clark subdivides the mesh *and* moves the geometry around to smooth the look.  Specifically I believe each vertex gets moved to the average position of itself and its neighbors with its own position being weighted twice.  Simple is usually used just to add more geometry for another modifier like displace to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can use the simple *Subsurf Subdivision Modifier* when additional geometry is required without the deformation that occurs when Catmull-Clark algorithm is used. 
Simple subsurf can create the geometry for a *Displacment Modifier* .
See this image its underlying geometry is a default torus. But has two subsurf modifiers and a displacement modifier.

[image]

Without the 2nd simple subsurf it would look like:

[image]

This technique is call UV-sculpting and a tutorial was posted at [this BA thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?273033-Sculpting-with-UVs-and-displacements).

Answer (score 6):

As an example of a case where *simple* is might be preferred over *Catmull-Clark*, say you have a large plane which you want to subdivide non-destructively for use with the displace modifier.

When subdivided with *Catmull-Clark*, it becomes nearly a circle:

[image]

But with *Simple* it maintains the original square shape:

[image]

This is just one example. There are probably many such use-cases where *Catmull-Clark* subdivision doesn't provide the desired result without extra things like edge-creases.

Answer (score 4):

About **Simple Subdivision** from the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Subsurf):

> Only subdivides the surfaces, **without any smoothing** (similar to <kbd>W</kbd> → Subdivide, in Edit mode). Can be used, for example, to increase base mesh resolution when using displacement maps or textured emitters with indirect lighting.

I think it's a suitable example. It's just an option to programmatically subdivide your object's geometry. It can be used to **add more detail to your geometry very quick** without e.g. manually placing new edge loops. The main advantage is that the modifier have **no effect on the appearance of the object** itself (non-destructive) unlike the catmull-clark algorithm.

For illustration purposes here is a simple test environment. *I've selected the real edges of the geometry to better see the difference between both modifiers.*

[image]
*Example geometry **without Subsurf***

[image]
*Example geometry with **Simple Subsurf***

[image]
*Example geometry with **Catmull Subsurf***

Note: There is a interesting [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface) about the Catmull algorithm.