# How can I hide emitting planes from view but keep the lighting effect?

Tags: materials

I want to fix the black area in the mirror.
I used Glossy BSDF to make it and I'm using cycle render.
And I want to know how to hide the cyan planes from the scene and keep their effect.

[image: The black area...]

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36503/making-an-invisible-material-in-the-cycles-render-engine/36507#36507

Comment: If it is mirror which is the question about in the left corner inside of cupboard then check modifiers for it (particulalry, Subsurf) and show the modifiers' stack.

Comment: It was without modifiers but I add subsurf and the black area has rounded it

Comment: So the black area appeared after you added Subsurf ?

Answer (score 2):

Starting with a scene like this:

[image]

Select the emitter objects and disable the ray visibility for camera and glossy.

[image]

As to why the round shape on your mirror.

If your mirror is rectangular you'll be gaining anything by adding a subsurf modifier to it. Subsurf modifier's default behavior is to round out geometry by interpolation:

[image]

[image]

If you **must** have the subsurf modifier change the interpolation from Catmull-Clark to Simple.

Comment: Thanks it worked, But the mirror

Comment: Please ask one question at the time.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19146/when-would-you-use-simple-subdivision-rather-than-catmull-clark-subdivision/19149#19149