# How to have emission plane light the scene including glossy objects but not show up in glass reflection?

Tags: light

Using Cycles.  I have lit and rendered 20 different objects with the same lighting set up.
Now using same setup to render a glass object, as part of the series.
However the emmissive plane used for lighting is now showing up in the glass reflection of this particular shot.

I don't want to change the lighting now.  Needs to be uniform across the previous 20 renders.

Tried turning off that light object's Glossy ray visibility, but that made the glossy objects around the glass too dark.

Is there another way to keep the scene just as well lit, but remove the plane's reflection from the glass?

I've got the impression from this [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44605/prevent-shadow-on-object-material-a-allow-for-object-material-b/44607#44607) that 'render layers' might have to be involved, but I'm quite new to blender, a bit short on time, and hoping for simpler method, if anyone knows.

[image: Reflection]

[image: nodes]

[image: glossy rays off vs refraction material]

Trying Leon Cheung's method:

[image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57603/how-can-i-hide-emitting-planes-from-view-but-keep-the-lighting-effect/57604#57604 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44649/how-to-get-rid-of-an-objects-reflection/44691#44691

Comment: Changing your glass material to refraction shader ?

Comment: @lemon tried just reftraction shader, and mixing refraction with transparency shader, but neither was transparent anymore, it seems, no matter what factor I used to mix the two.  Needs to be transparent for background purpose.

Comment: glass on the left, refraction on the right  : https://i.gyazo.com/c95c1f7e16df930e96b738e64d9a32c0.png. Think about refraction to be a not glossy glass (only keeps IOR). But as the glossy aspect is lost for every objects, I don't know if it can be an answer

Comment: Thanks @cegaton.  Wish it worked, but makes my other objects too dark, by turning visibility of glossy rays of emitter off.  Attached image to question.

Comment: @lemon, I'm not sure how to achieve the refraction material shown on the right.  Edited my post to show my refraction material nodes and the result - no longer transparent.  Can you share the nodes?  Thanks

Comment: Have you set the film to transparent in the render panel ?

Comment: The answer below is totally correct. However, you always want to have reflection on glossy surfaces if they should look relistic.

Answer (score 3):

For the emission plane material, you can make use of **Singular Ray** to get rid of perfect reflection and transmission.

Comparision:

[image]

Comment: Hello and thanks... that requires some roughness in the glossy shader, am I right ?

Comment: @Leon Cheung, your solution looks great, exactly what I want.  But my result does not match your result.  I posted a screenshot of my results in the question.  Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: @sliver Hmm, maybe you could share the file? That would be really helpful for improving the answer.

Comment: @lemon it seems you are right, I'll have a deeper look.

Comment: I think we missed a big point: Cycles doesn't support per-object light path, which means, you CANNOT disable ray visibility of the emission plane for particular object. So it has to be done with help of render layer, object or material index, and post-composition I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

A complement solution (as the one from [Leon Cheung](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/696/leon-cheung) is good) but we start commenting too much below the question.

[image]

In order to have transparency, two things are needed :

- A transparency shader
- Setting the film to transparent in the render panel

[image]

Concerning the node for the glass part :

The refraction shader replaces the glass shader (see it like a non glossy glass).
And the transparent shader is needed to have the wanted overall transparency.

[image]

[image]