# What does simple sub-surf do?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface, geometry

I recently modeled a cupboard in blender to be sold in turbosquid . I read somewhere that a simple sub-surf modifier would make my normal model to a *high poly* model. So I added a simple sub-surf modifier and applied it. That was the first ti,e that I used a simple sub-surf and never knew what it'd do. When I went to edit mode it had a lot of loopcuts which was making my PC laggy . ***Is it really that necessary to add in this much geometry to the mesh? Why is it needed and where is it used?*** [image]

Thank you.

Comment: No I don't wanna sculpt my model .I was just experimenting with the modifers

Comment: In sites like turbosquid I have seen a lot of models with unwanted subdivisions. I wish to know why the are doing it ,where all are they used ?

Comment: Simple, compared to Catmull-Clark, add geometry without smoothing, as explained here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19146/when-would-you-use-simple-subdivision-rather-than-catmull-clark-subdivision ... As Christopher says there seems no reason to use Subdivision Surface, unless you have a good reason. To give a bit of smoothness on the angles you can simply add bevels, it will make the object a bit more natural.

Comment: Related: [When and when not to use subdivsion surfaces?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/112221/78972)

Comment: @christopher Bennett it will be helpful if you post the comment as the answer. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Moonboots the link you have shared is very helpful...It explains most of my question . Thanks a lot for replying

Comment: @ Nxdhin2005 Alright, done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record, all "Simple" Subdivision Surface Modifier does is subdivide your model, only it does it in the temporary, non-destructive manner that modifiers do (until you apply it).

Unless you are looking to add extra detail to your model, there is no reason to make a high poly version of it. It's my impression that lower poly count models are preferred on sites like TurboSquid.

Often models sold on sites like that come with 2 versions - a high poly and a low poly. The high poly generally is good for still images and renders, but has an unacceptable number of faces to be used in something such as a game engine. For this, people can either use the low poly model, or bake the normal information from the high poly to the low poly to add the look of detail without adding actual geometry.

If used in a game engine, the unmodified low poly can also be used as a LOD (Level Of Detail) model for times when the object is visible, but too far away for detail to matter. So all, in all, you should be aiming  to use as little geometry as possible in the models you plan to sell. You only need as much subdivision as your detail requires for it to "look good"